# Yii2 how to create table template using select2 widget

Tags: php, html, yii2, jquery-select2

I have a dropdown list using select2 widget to get the customer contact

```
$getcontact = ArrayHelper::map(OpContact::find()->all(),'id','code');

 <div class="col-md-10">'.
                     $form->field($model, 'contact_id')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
                          'data' => $getcontact,
                          'language' => 'en',
                          'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select'],
                          'pluginOptions' => [
                              'allowClear' => true
                          ],                             
                      ])->label(false).'
```

For now, its just a normal dropdownlist which show only the contact id.How I can like insert 2nd column for it and put all the data inside a table. For example, I want the dropdown to look like this where I can see the id and the contact name together.

```
------------------------------
     ID         Contact ID
------------------------------
     21          contact1
     22          contact2
     23          contact3
     24          contact1
```

Anyone have any idea? Thanks

Comment: you want to store id and want to display id - code ?

Comment: @YasinPatel yaya

Answer (score 0):

if you want store only the id and see both  id and contactID and contact ID is th concat of id and code  you couuld use

```
$getcontact = ArrayHelper::map(OpContact::find()
               ->select('id, concat(id, code) as contactID')
               ->all(),'id','contactID');
```

if you want store both  you can

```
$getcontact = ArrayHelper::map(OpContact::find()
               ->select('concat(id, code) as id, concat(id, code) as contactID')
               ->all(),'id','contactID');
```

Comment: okayy thankss. But it is possible to put like what I draw up there, putting whole table inside the dropdown list?

Comment: what do you mean with "put the whole table inside .." ..?  all the rows selected by find() ...->all()  are showed in dropdown ..

Comment: ermm the dropdown will look like a table. With top row showing ID and contaact, then i can choose the data listed below

Comment: if you mean that you need an header  for column name  .. then you should  build a new widget .. that manage the aspect of the dropdown and the select  of the row but not for the header ...i think that is a lot of code ..

Answer (score 0):

you can't show all of them , but you can merge that field in string mode in your query like CONCAT  or in your foreach merge string with " . "  together

Answer (score 0):

Change `ArrayHelper` as below .

```
$getcontact = ArrayHelper::map(OpContact::find()->all(),'id',function($model){ return $model->id.'-'.$model->code; });
```